# Почему возникает ошибка "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class '...' not found in ..." при загрузке библиотеки через Composer?

Tags: php, composer, namespace

Написал (но и сейчас пишу) библиотеку для работы с API.
Для библиотеки создал папку с названием **amoNG** и туда при разработке поместил все файлы
[image]

- **src/AmoNG** - исходники библиотеки
- **projects** - провожу локальные тесты библиотеки, т.е. инициализирую ее там и работаю с ней

До этого структура была другой, все файлы были не в **src/AmoNG**, а рядом с папкой **projects**. До этого момента composer все видел и всё работало.
Но сейчас я посмотрел как сделана структура в других репозиториях, изменил ее, залил **composer.json** и загрузил в **packagist**.
Мой **composer.json** для **packagist**'а:

```
{
    "name": "myname/among",
    "description": "PHP библиотека",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "AGPL-3.0",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "MyName",
            "email": "MyMail"
        }
    ],
    "keywords": ["API", "amoCRM", "amoNG"],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-fileinfo": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "AmoNG\\": "src/AmoNG" }
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "vendor/bin",
        "process-timeout": 600
    }
}
```

Внутри **src/AmoNG** такая структура:
[image]
Сейчас в **projects** создаю файл для проверки библиотеки, ввожу `composer require myname/among:dev-master`, всё прогружается, подключаю `require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');`
И при попытке инициализировать класс из библиотеки, выскакивает ошибка

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class '...' not found in ...

Пытаюсь в тестовом файле папки **projects** инициализировать класс **Logger** и выпадает вышеописанная ошибка.
В файле **Logger** такая начальная структура:

```
<?php

namespace AmoNG;

class Logger
{
```

Когда я сделал **require** внутри **projects**, сформировался **composer.json** такого содержания:

```
{
    "require": {
        "myname/among": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Я ничего там не менял.
Также, попытался сделать инициализацию класса в папке **Entities**, например, **Companies**, также вылетает ошибка.
У файла **Companies** такое начало:

```
<?php

namespace AmoNG\Entities;

use AmoNG\Entities\AbstractEntity;

/**
 * класс для работы с компаниями
 */
class Companies extends AbstractEntity
{
```

[image]
Начальный код тестового файла в папке **projects** при инициализации класса **Logger**:

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

use AmoNG\Logger;
```

А также **Companies**:

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

use AmoNG\Entities\Companies;
```

Суть: почему я не могу получить доступ к классам? Структуру я соблюдаю, **namespace** адекватно написал, по иерархии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

оказывается, что если локально написать код, а потом его загрузить на github, сразу сделать require в composer, то будет загружен старый код (если до этого репозиторий индексировался в packagist). Возникает это из-за того, что packagist около 5 минут синхранизируется с репозиторием github.
Из-за этого у меня методы были недоступны. 
Итого: 
- или  ждать синхронизации файлов на стороне packagist
- или подключать через composer пакет локально, тестировать и по итогу делать push на github

Comment: Чтобы этого избежать, запускайте composer clearcache перед composer install/update.

Comment: благодарен за ответ! учту. но я удалял вендор-папку и компоузер-файл, устанавливал с нуля. поэтому сделал вывод, что у пакейджиста есть задержка при синхронизации